# SwiftUI image capturing View breaks EnvironmentObjects?

Tags: swiftui

I am attempting to capture a screenshot of my view in SwiftUI. I have tried with both the `ImageRenderer(content: myview)` and with the below `snapshot` View extension. On both cases it crashes giving the error . . .

> Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type isActive found. A
> View.environmentObject(_:) for isActive may be missing as
> an ancestor of this view.

I have tried both an empty environment object and the object with variables and it always get the same error. Is there any way to allow the use of environment objects when programmatically capturing a screenshot?

```
//main view
struct TestView111: View {    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            otherview
            //click this to capture screenshot and break on environment var
            Button(action: {
                let image = otherview.snapshot()
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
            }, label: {
                Text("Save").buttonStyleBlue()
            })
        }
    }
    //view to take snapshot of
    var otherview: some View {
        TestView112()
    }
}

//sub view
struct TestView112: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var objRect: GraphObjectRectList
    
    var body: some View {
        //can no longer find isActive here and breaks on btn click
        ForEach(objRect.isActive.indices, id: \.self) { i in
            Text(String(i))
        }
    }
}

//extension to take snapshot
extension View {
    func snapshot() -> UIImage {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        let view = controller.view
        let size = CGSize(width: 500, height: 500)
        view?.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        view?.backgroundColor = .clear

        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size)

        return renderer.image { _ in
            view?.drawHierarchy(in: controller.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
}

//my Environment class
class GraphObjectRectList: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isActive: [Bool] = [true, true]
}

//Scene View
struct TestAppApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TestView111()
                .environmentObject(GraphObjectRectList())
        }
    }
}
```

Is the graphics rendering engine is unable to access the global object twice?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You aren't injecting the object using `environmentObject(...)` anywhere.

Comment: @jnpdx what do you mean, there's a simple loop over it in the subview? It's created on my Scene with `.environmentObject(GraphObjectRectList())` if that's what you mean.

Comment: Then you should show the relevant code (in a [mre])

Comment: @jnpdx oh ok, my bad, I'll add it.

Comment: If the error is that there isn't an environmentObject, the most logical conclusion is that you haven't injected it (it's a common issue seen here), so definitely good to include it. And, always important to include a [mre]

Comment: @jnpdx Thanks! I updated the question to have that part of my code, should I change how I'm injecting it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your current example, the `EnvironmentObject` doesn't exist on `otherview` because `otherview` doesn't exist in the view hierarchy -- it exists on its own in the `Button`'s `action`.

To solve this, inject it on the version you're sending to `snapshot`:

```
struct TestView111: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var objRect: GraphObjectRectList //<-- Here

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            otherview //<-- This one has a reference to the object, since it's in the view hierarchy
            Button(action: {
                let image = otherview.environmentObject(objRect).snapshot() //<-- Here
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
            }, label: {
                Text("Save")
            })
        }
    }
    //view to take snapshot of
    var otherview: some View {
        TestView112()
    }
}
```